# Passing $(Configuration) as parameter to External Tool in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, batch-file, external-tools

I am trying to pass the $(Configuration) macro as a parameter to an external tool (batch file), however, it apears to be empty. I tried by calling a simple test.bat that echo's the %1 parameter and pass the $(Configuration) macro as a param. Nothing is displayed however. Any ideas anyone

Comment: How exactly have you tried to pass it to the batch file?

Comment: In the add external tool window there is a parameters textbox, I just entered it in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(Configuration)` is not listed as one of the defined IDE arguments that can be used when defining an external tool.

See [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekbzk5f8.aspx) for the defined ones - since `$(Configuration)` is not listed, it is not something that can be used as an argument for an external tool.

Comment: @Colin - Not that I am aware of. Apart from the defined arguments, there is no way to make this dynamic. You _can_ define the external tool _multiple times_ - for each configuration.

Comment: Prob. going to do that. Where does VS store the currently selection Configuration? In the .sln file? Maybe I could extract that?

Comment: @Colin - Not in the `.sln`. Possibly in the `.suo` file (as this is user specific).

Comment: Hmm, thought so, but there's suo file.. Will just go with the different calls then...